# How to expand $(x+y)^{3/2}-(x-y)^{3/2}$ for $x\gg y$

Tags: taylor-expansion

My first and naive impression is that the result is 0 but according to *Salinas, Introduction to Statistical Physics* that's

- $3x^{1/2}y + O[(x/y)^3]$

I think Taylor expansion would do it. The thing is, I don't really know around what point I should do it.
Could anyone help here?

Thank you

Comment: Write $(x\pm y)^{3/2}$ as $\displaystyle x^{3/2} \cdot \left(1 + {y \over x}\right)^{3/2}$ and do an expansion around $a=1$. (And are you sure about the $O((x/y)^3)$? Methinks it should be $O((y/x)^3)$, otherwise, the error is unbounded.)

Comment: You don't need to write $x>>y$; you can write $x\gg y$.  I changed it. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy Good to know. Tks.

Comment: Yet another way of looking at it: this is approximately $2y\frac{d}{dx}(x^{3/2})$, since it's the numerator of the central derivative approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint and some ideas**

Write them as follows

$$x^{3/2}\left[1 + \frac{y}{x}\right]^{3/2} - x^{3/2}\left[1 - \frac{y}{x}\right]^{3/2}$$

that is

$$x^{3/2}\left[\left(1 + \frac{y}{x}\right)^{3/2} - \left(1 - \frac{y}{x}\right)^{3/2}\right]$$

Now you can apply binomial series for example

$$(1 + X)^{\alpha} \approx 1 + \alpha X + \cdots $$

$$(1 - X)^{\alpha} \approx 1 - \alpha X + \cdots $$

Thence you get

$$x^{3/2}\left[1 + \frac{3}{2}\frac{y}{x} - 1 + \frac{3}{2}\frac{y}{x}\right] = x^{3/2}\cdot 3\frac{y}{x} = 3x^{1/2} y$$

Thence since here your work works!

Then you can proceed with more terms in the Binomial Series to catch the Error or whatever..

Comment: You need another term to get the error.

Comment: @CarlHeckman Well that was a hint! Since the work is set, the OP can proceed.. I hope!

Comment: Yeap, just did it. And I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a naive approach to get the main term using only algebra:  recall the difference of cubes identity $$a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2 + ab + b^2).$$  Then with the choice $a = (x+y)^{1/2}$, $b = (x-y)^{1/2}$, and in the case $x \ge |y|$, we can also write $x+y = a^2$, $x-y = b^2$; hence $$a-b = \frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b} = \frac{(x+y)-(x-y)}{a+b} = \frac{2y}{a+b},$$ and $$a^2 + ab + b^2 = 2x + (x^2 - y^2)^{1/2}.$$  Thus the given expression is identically equal to $$\frac{2y(2x + \sqrt{x^2-y^2})}{\sqrt{x+y} + \sqrt{x-y}}.$$  In the case where $x$ greatly exceeds $y$, the numerator is essentially $2y(3x) = 6xy$, and the denominator is approximately $2\sqrt{x}$.  Therefore, the given expression is roughly $3x^{1/2} y$, as claimed.

To get the error term is a bit more involved, and to that end, the other answers furnish a more generally applicable method; but in my opinion it is worth seeing the above computation, which is easily accessible to a high school student.